# Lightweight Windows HTTP server for static content from CD/DVD

Tags: windows, http, lightweight, http-server

I need a very lightweight Windows HTTP server to put onto CD/DVD. I've tried just using “file:” “protocol”, but there're too many problems:

1. IE disallows JavaScript by default. There's a workaround with “saved from internet” comment, but CSS3 Pie using HTC still doesn't work from a local drive.
2. JavaScript needs to generate files and let the user save them. HTML5 File Writer API has almost no support, data URIs have size limits in IE, don't let setting default file name etc. The only viable solution seems to be Downloadify which uses Flash. And this feature doesn't work when HTML and SWF are loaded from local drive.
3. AJAX doesn't work at all.

**So, I need a server with the following properties:**

1. No installation, relies only on config file(s).
2. Can be executed from a read-only folder.
3. MIME types can be configured for file extensions. (IE is sometimes picky about HTC.)
4. Runs on Windows XP/Vista/7.

Comment: Have you considered making this an HTA application instead?  It should do everything you've asked for

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [HTTP File Server](http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/). It's been a while since I've used it, but it may be what you're looking for.

Comment: HFS looked promising, it has all the features I've asked for, but it only works with absolute file paths which makes running preconfigured HFS from CD/DVD impossible. :( And even more problems appear, HTC components don't work for some reason. Maybe IE has a separate setting for localhost IPs...